# select or deselect checkboxes on condition in Angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<input id="discover" type="checkbox" (click)="subfilters()" value="Selling assets" name="Selling Assets" style="  text-align:center;  padding-left: 156px;">Discover
```

Above is my HTML code to click on check box. So I need to put a condition like if I click on this button go to subfilters() function and check the checkbox is checked or not, then execute the code inside the check box condition.

Comment: What problem is exactly coming?

Answer (score 0):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/acT2yqBDB29VnpQYjQoy?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Try Following code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Test App</h1>
  <label><input type="checkbox"  [checked]="checkbox1" (click)='showPopup($event)'/> Oops! </label>

  `
})
export class AppComponent { 

  checkbox1 = false;

  showPopup(e) { 

    alert(e.target.checked);
  } 
}
```

Hope that solve your problem.